# Manipulating the pdf of the multivariate gaussian to arrive at the univariate

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

On the PDF of a multivariate gaussian, we have $e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^t\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}$

On the univariate gaussian, we have $e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu)^t(x-\mu)}{\sigma^2}}$ (written in a weird notation to emphasize the similarity)

I already know that if you take a $x$ from a multivariate gaussian and $x=a \cdot x$, $x'$ is a univariate gaussian with variance $a^t \cdot \Sigma \cdot a$ (see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504181/projection-of-a-multivariate-normal-into-a-univariate-normal-calculating-varian)

My question: It should be possible, using the facts

1. that $\Sigma$ is positive semi definite
2. that $a^t \cdot \Sigma \cdot a$ is $\sigma$ if $a$ has $a^t \cdot a = 1$

And

3. assuming $a^t \cdot a = 1$

To prove that $a^t \cdot \Sigma^{-1} \cdot a$ is $\sigma^{-1}$

(do note that I am rather confused. I am not sure that 2 is a fact, though it seems to follow from what I said)

(also, do note that I am asking for a particular path of proof: One that does not go through the machinery of statistics, but rather through linear algebra. I could just say "the resulting distribution is normal univariate" and follow with "therefore the exponent is as asked". But when I try to do the math without recourse to this, just evaluating, I seem not to get the desired result)

Comment: Assume $\Sigma$ is p.d. Then $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_p)^T\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)\implies a^TX\sim N(a^T\mu,a^T\Sigma a)$ for any $a\in \mathbb R^p$. If you choose $a$ to be a unit vector, say $a=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$, then you get the distribution of $X_1$.

Comment: Thanks! Though this does not give me an answer to a general a. Also, I added some extra clarification on the question as to what kind of proof I am looking for -- sorry for not being clearer earlier!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by general $a$; it has to be a unit vector. Changing the position of $1$ in $a$, you get the distribution of all components of $X$. In my last comment, you do get $a^T\mu=\mu_1$ and $a^T\Sigma a=\sigma_{11}$ if $\mu_1$ is the first component of $\mu$ and $\sigma_{11}$ is the $(1,1)$th entry of $\Sigma$.

Comment: sorry, yes, your comment deals with all a. I seem not to have read it carefully enough. Still I am looking for a proof with a specific format, so that I can better understand the linear algebra involved. I assume some statistics on "fact 2", and then hope to make it to the finish line on linear algebra alone